# Haskell program will not end if input = 0

Tags: haskell

When the user inputs number m = 0, the program will never stop counting. Is there any way how to take care of that? so if the user inputs 0 the program will end.

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

transpose :: [[a]]->[[a]]
transpose ([]:_) = []
transpose x = (map head x) : transpose (map tail x)
.
.
.
```

Comment: You do not have to define your own transposition function. Just import Data.List (transpose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a case in transpose that is triggered by entering 0:

```
transpose :: [[a]]->[[a]]
transpose [] = []
transpose ([]:_) = []
transpose x = (map head x) : transpose (map tail x)
```

And the above is quite dangerous, as 'head' and 'tail' might fail:

```
transpose [[0],[]]
```

[[0,*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

Answer (score 2):

Your transpose function does not work for empty matrices represented as empty lists `[]`.

The first equation,

```
transpose ([]:_) = []
```

handles only empty matrices that have at least one empty row.

The second case will recurse infinitely for an empty list:

```
transpose [] = [] : transpose []
```

So, just add one more equation, before the general `transpose x` equation:

```
transpose [] = []
```